# Where does the optimal point of production occur in the graph of short-run cost curves?

Tags: production-function, cost, marginal

When MC, ATC, AVC, and AFC are in the same diagram, where does the optimal point of production occur? I know production is optimal when MR=MC but the question doesn't give you the price of the good. If the ATC is at its lowest at two different points (Q=60 and Q=70 in this case), does that mean everything in between 60 and 70 are optimal points of production? The point of diminishing marginal returns starts at Q=60. If it's the ATC that matters, is Q=60 the optimal point of production since marginal product diminishes further after 60 (MC=$4.00 atQ=60 and $6.60 at Q=70)? I don't know what I'm supposed to look for to determine the optimal point of production when you can't calculate revenue. Is it the point of diminishing marginal returns or the segment in which ATC is at the lowest? Thank you.

Comment: Is the firm a monopolist or a competitive firm? If it is a monopolist, then you need the demand function to determine the profit-maximizing output. If it is a competitive firm, then you could calculate the profit-maximizing output for every price (i.e. find the supply function). Perhaps if you gave us the details of the question then we could be of more help.